# Off-Canvas Menu in Sencha Touch 2.3 ('setMenu') doesn't work on Android 2.3

Tags: android, extjs, menu, sencha-touch-2, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've implemented the new Menu Component [setMenu(menu, config)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.viewport.Default). It works perfectly on Android 4.x, iOS6 and iOS7, but it doesn't work properly on Android 2.3 (neither on device nor on emulator). I've followed the sample code of [their sample in kitchen sink](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/touch-build/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/menus).

**Is anyone out there who got this working on Android 2.3?**

I've put together a small sample and this is how it looks in Chrome, on Android 4.x, on iOS6 and iOS7:

[image] [image]

This is how it looks on Android 2.3 after clicking "showMenu":

[image]

This is how I add the Menu:

```
initialize: function() {
    var menu = Ext.create('MenuTest.view.MenuView');

    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
        side: 'right',
        cover:  false
    });

    this. add({
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'showMenu',
        listeners: {
            tap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
                Ext.Viewport.toggleMenu('right');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My MenuView has only a single label:

```
config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'Test Menu'
        }
    ]
}
```

**Is anyone out there who got this working on Android 2.3?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the **setMenu** method in *touch-src-Default-viewport*... Our fix:

```
// if (menu.$reveal) {  // original
   if (Ext.os.is.Android && Ext.os.version.lt('3') || menu.$reveal) {  // fixed
       Ext.getBody().insertFirst(menu.element);
       // Bugfix: inner buttons of slider overlap original container while sliding - change z-index
       Ext.get('ext-viewport').setStyle('z-index', '1');
    }

// if (menu.$reveal) {  // original
   if (Ext.os.is.Android && Ext.os.version.lt('3') || menu.$reveal) {  // fixed
       if (Ext.browser.getPreferredTranslationMethod() != 'scrollposition') {
           menu.translate(0, 0);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short snippet based on your answer which you e.g. can place into the top of your `launch()` function (or with the other ST fixes):

```
// Bugfix for Off-Canvas menu in Android 2.3
Ext.viewport.Android.override({
  showMenu: function (side) {
    if (Ext.os.version.lt('3')) {
      Ext.get('ext-viewport').setStyle('z-index', '1');
      this.getMenus()[side].$reveal = true;
    }
    this.callOverridden([side]);
  }
});
```